# Replace the empty element of an array with another array or with another element in javascript | javascript | array

Tags: javascript, arrays

let say I have an array in javascript with the following content.

```
let arr = [1, 2, , 4]; // [1, 2, empty, 4]
arr[5] = 6; // [1, 2, empty, 4, empty, 6]
```

as you can see that the arr variable has an empty value in the 2nd and 4th position. and I want to fill these empty values with the array provided as for filling like

```
let replace_empty_with = [3, 5];
```

So, first of all, I want to know whether an array has empty value or not so I use the following methods

```
arr.includes(undefined);
// or
Object.values(arr).length == arr.length
```

Now how can I fill the empty value of the original array(arr variable) with the value of the replace_empty_with array variable?

**Desired output**
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

I have tried with the forEach function of array to know if the particular element has undefined or null value but I did not get success.

also, I have tried with indexOf to find the first undefined element of the array but it always returns -1 as indexOf(undefined) - state that there is no undefined element in the array.

Comment: Overall, I think I have tried with forEach and indexOf but there are more methods available to detect the empty element in the array. I surprised by the behavior of the forEach and indexOf function that totally avoids holes in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've create a [sparse array](https://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) (an array with the holes). Array methods such as `Array.forEach()` or `Array.map()` skip this holes.

You can use `Array.from()` to iterate the sparse array, and generate a new array by taking values from `replace_empty_with` when the current index (`i`) doesn't exist in the original array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, , 4]; // [1, 2, empty, 4]
arr[5] = 6; // [1, 2, empty, 4, empty, 6]

const replace_empty_with = [3, 5];

const result = Array.from(arr, (v, i) => i in arr ? 
  v
  :
  replace_empty_with.shift()
)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator, to detect holes in an array.

Iterate over it, and fill:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4, , 6]
let replace_empty_with = [3, 5]

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(!(i in arr) && replace_empty_with.length) arr[i] = replace_empty_with.shift()
}

console.log(arr)
```

Note that the `in` operator has the advantage (or disadvantage, depending on the goal) to detect properties with explicit value `undefined` as defined.

That is, the above code won't fill anything in the following:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, undefined, 4, undefined]
```

To replace those as well, use `=== undefined` instead:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4, , 6]
let replace_empty_with = [3, 5]

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== (void 0) && replace_empty_with.length) arr[i] = replace_empty_with.shift()
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I liked the `i in arr` check.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop can be used like this:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4]; // [1, 2, empty, 4]
arr[5] = 6; // [1, 2, empty, 4, empty, 6]
let replace_empty_with = [3, 5];

let nextPos = 0
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === undefined) {
    arr[i] = replace_empty_with[nextPos++]
    if (nextPos >= replace_empty_with.length) break
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: was typing this same thing, beat me by seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `...` spread operator before the array having holes, to convert the holes into `undefined`.

Once you do that the `Array.prototype.map` can be used to check for the presence of `undefined` values and if found replace that with the one from the replacement array:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4]; // [1, 2, empty, 4]
arr[5] = 6; // [1, 2, empty, 4, empty, 6]
let replace_empty_with = [3, 5];

function replaceEmpty(arr, replacer){
 return [...arr].map(e => e === undefined ? replacer.shift() : e);
}
console.log(replaceEmpty(arr, replace_empty_with));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a loop and check if some elements are available to add to the array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, , 4],
    replace = [3, 5];

for (let i = 0; replace.length; i++) {
    if (i in array) continue;
    array[i] = replace.shift();
}

console.log(array);
```